# Linux (ubuntu) permissions for webapp - UNIQUE SITUATION

Tags: php, linux, web-applications, lampp

I have a typical webapp running on LAMPP - and that's were typical ends. How the users of the webapp get access to it is by installing an Ubuntu VM (virtual machine) locally. They open the browser within the VM and they get to index.php (landing page of the webapp).

Now, I want the webapp to have access to the htdocs directory but I don't want the currently logged in user ("webappUser") to be able to open/read any of the source files in htdocs.

Example:

User 1: webappAdmin - has root access to htdocs

User 2: webappUser  - does NOT read/write access to htdocs

Anyone have any recommendations? THANKS for your help!!

Comment: Wait... you have what you call a 'webapp' that *requires* the user to install a Ubuntu VM?? Something is missing in this question..... Is this some attempt at a configuration/learning examination?

Comment: Yeah, I know it is weird. The Webapp is a lab testing app which requires the server to be local to the user. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Apache has it's own user (normally www-data on ubuntu) rather than accessing the files as the logged in user. What I would do is chown the htdocs folder to webappAdmin:webappAdmin, add www-data to the webappAdmin group and set permissions on the folder to 640 (webappAdmin has read/write, www-data can read the files and thus serve them, and anyone else, including webappUser, has no access at all).

Comment: thanks @erm410. That makes sense, now I just need to figure out how to actualize it. Is this along the right lines?  sudo chown -R webappAdmin: webappAdmin /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/lampp/htdocs
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs'

Comment: `sudo chown -R webappAdmin:webappAdmin /opt/lampp/htdocs sudo adduser www-data webappAdmin sudo chmod -R 640 /opt/lampp/htdocs` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks - just tried it (looged in as webappAdmin) and got permission denied to the index.php (through browser). umm..

Comment: ls: cannot access /opt/lampp/htdocs/webalizer: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /opt/lampp/htdocs/csk2: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /opt/lampp/htdocs/csk: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? csk
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? csk2
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? favicon.ico
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? index.php
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? webalizer
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? xampp

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part, using `chmod -R 640` since directories need to be executable. Use 750 instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11445/discussion-between-erm410-and-ven)

Comment: total 60
drwxr-x--- 16 csk csk 12288 May 16 17:44 csk
drwxr-x--- 16 csk csk  4096 May 16 15:29 csk2
-rwxr-x---  1 csk csk 30894 May 11  2007 favicon.ico
-rwxr-x---  1 csk csk   256 Feb  5  2009 index.php
drwxr-x---  2 csk csk  4096 May 16 15:16 webalizer
drwxr-x---  7 csk csk  4096 May 16 15:16 xampp
csk@csk-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$

Comment: thanks mate - I got it working. I had to add www-data + nobody to the admin group. I also took ownership of the specific directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webapp instead of htdocs. The system freaked when taking ownership of htdocs. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can give the users a prebuilt VHD (or whatever format you are using for the virtual machine), then you can setup users prior to the distribution. With that, you can set the proper permissions for each folder or even a per file basis if needed. Create a non root/limited/guest account in Ubuntu and hand out that login. However, savvy users would still be able to login via [single user mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73442/how-do-i-login-in-single-user-mode), effectively gaining root permissions anyway.

What I would suggest doing, is creating a local limited account on the server you have the application on (since you said they *need* local server access) and installing a [VNC Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers). From there, you hand out the VNC address and the limited local account credentials to those who need access.

Comment: the webapp/vm is a bubble (lab) with non routable IPs. So there has to be one webapp server per user. Kinda of a linux newbie here so I am trying to figure out the right permissions for the webappUser but still allow apache access to /opt/lampp/htdocs/